# convert data struct to another data struct in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, converters

I am facing a problem of converting one data structure in Python into another data structure (JSON I think). Are there some smart ways in Python I can tackle this? Some mapping system perhaps?
What approach can I take to convert this dictionary coming from CSV file

```
{
   "id":1,
   "surname":"Einstein",
   "givennames":"Albert",
   "dateofbirth":"27/08/2007",
   "address":"11 Willow Road,BOSTON MANOR",
   "postcode":"AXT 5JA",
   "mobile":"078 1453 6934"
}
```

into the following structure...

```
[
   {
      "metadata":{
         "type":"pole_model",
         "version":"0.1"
      },
      "party":[
         {
            "source_system":"A",
            "source_id":"1",
            "person":{
               "surname":"Einstein",
               "given_names":"Albert",
               "date_of_birth":"27/08/2007"
            }
         }
      ],
      "location":[
         {
            "source_system":"A",
            "source_id":"1",
            "address":{
               "line_1":"11 Willow Road,BOSTON MANOR",
               "postcode":"AXT 5JA"
            }
         },
         {
            "contact":{
               "source_system":"A",
               "source_id":"1",
               "phone":{
                  "mobile":"078 1453 6934"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: I don't think there are any quick or built-in ways of doing this. Chances are you'll need to write the code yourself

Comment: okay, do you know of any approaches I can take to achieve this? some templating approach? mapping perhaps?

Comment: You'll have to define the mapping (i.e. the correspondence between inputs and outputs) first, then come up with a way to code that up. At the moment, your output contains more data than your input (source_system and metadata).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple way that inserts source data into a template. The `metadata` and `source_system` values could additionally be passed into the function.

```py
def convert(source):
    return {
      "metadata": {
         "type": "pole_model",
         "version": "0.1"
      },
      "party":[
         {
            "source_system": "A",
            "source_id": str(source["id"]),
            "person":{
               "surname": source["surname"],
               "given_names": source["givennames"],
               "date_of_birth": source["dateofbirth"]
            }
         }
      ],
      "location":[
         {
            "source_system": "A",
            "source_id": str(source["id"]),
            "address":{
               "line_1": source["address"],
               "postcode": source["postcode"]
            }
         },
         {
            "contact":{
               "source_system": "A",
               "source_id": str(source["id"]),
               "phone":{
                  "mobile": source["mobile"]
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
```